# Using a rails engine in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rails-engines

How can I create a rails engine inside of a spec test? I would be using it to test a gem. 
Here is what I am trying

```
module Zan
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
    isolate_namespace MyEngine
  end
end
```

and I am getting

```
 Failure/Error: class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
 NameError:
   uninitialized constant Rails
```

I've tried `bundle exec rake spec` with the same result.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add rails as a dependency of the gem, and require it in the spec helper:

```
# your_gem.gemspec

spec.add_development_dependency 'rails'


# spec_helper.rb

require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler/setup'
```